# How to add tag text as id to tagit.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

How to add id to each tag in the span with class tagit-label? I need to add tag text as id to tag added.

```
<ul id="singleFieldTags" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
   <li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
      <span class="tagit-label">Others</span>
      <a class="tagit-close">
      <span class="text-icon">×</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable"><span class="tagit-label">Facebook</span><a class="tagit-close"><span class="text-icon">×</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a></li>
   <li class="tagit-new"><input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"><span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.  
</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.tagit-label').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id',$(this).text());
 });
```

Comment: It's working but when i add another tag id is not added to that new element.

Comment: you need to re execute above code after adding the new element.